# Do symlinks from HDD to SSD give a performance hit?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, symbolic-link

I am planning to install Kubuntu onto an SSD, but have */home* mounted on a hard disk drive.
But also, I would like some */home/...* subdirectories to benefit from SSD's performance (they will be read often and written rarely).

An obvious solution for this is to create symbolic links to some location on the solid-state drive.
However, I was under the impression that symlinks are similar to files in a way, and to get to the files on the SSD, the computer would have to read the symlink from the HDD first.

So my question is the following:
Do symbolic links from a (normal) hard disk drive to a solid-state drive (both *ext4* formatted) lead to a significant performance hit? Can I just use them or should I look for another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not lead to a performance hit.  The link has to be read, but only once.  After that it will be kept in the cache.

Comment: That's nice to hear, but can you provide some references/proof?

Comment: There are two exceptions, Recursive links (i.e. /filea links to /fileb that links to /filea) and when the HDD is spun down (it will take time to spool drive). But there is no performance hit on links themselves.

Comment: [this reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26897/117844) says something that makes sense, after the file have been opened it doesn't matter if it was found using a symlink or not, the inode is already open and now OS will use the stream connection.

Comment: [This is](https://serverfault.com/questions/610600/performance-hit-from-moving-db-to-another-drive-symlink) another good reference

Answer (score 2):

You could keep the whole of /home in SSD, and mount only the Documents, Pictures, etc in the harddisk. Consider this solution as in my computer:

```
/disk/zero/bin /home/sddhrthrt/bin      auto bind 0 0
/disk/zero/Documents /home/sddhrthrt/Documents  auto bind 0 0
/disk/zero/dotfiles /home/sddhrthrt/dotfiles    auto bind 0 0
/disk/zero/srv      /home/sddhrthrt/srv         auto bind 0 0
```

in your `/etc/fstab`. I'm not sure if this is better than symlinking, but I guess it performs better. (I did it for backup/sharing purposes anyway, because I do the same folders with other distros too).

And you should consider mounting your `/var` in the harddisk if you haven't already.